# error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>

Tags: c++, iterator, shared-ptr, stdmap, directed-graph

I'm trying to delete a node for a general directed weighted graph. When I delete a node, I also need to delete the incoming and outgoing edges of that node, so I cannot just delete the node, but also have to delete the edges that are attached to other nodes that used to link to this node before it is deleted.

For the function, I'm trying to find the linking node by using the find() function, which is used to find a node within nodes_, which is declared as:

```
std::map< N, std::shared_ptr<Node> > nodes_;
```

I tried originNodeOfIncomingEdge->edges_.erase(edge); but it doesn't work, so I'm trying to do the following in order to find the node on the map of nodes_ before doing an erase.

```
auto findLinkingNode1 = nodes_.find(originNodeOfIncomingEdge);
```

However, I keep getting the following error, not sure what is wrong.

```
tests/Graph.tem:558:64: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::shared_ptr<gdwg::Graph<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>::Node>, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::shared_ptr<gdwg::Graph<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>::Node> > > >::find(std::shared_ptr<gdwg::Graph<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>::Node>&)’
    auto findLinkingNode1 = nodes_.find(originNodeOfIncomingEdge);
                                                                ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/map:61:0,
                 from tests/Graph.h:19,
                 from tests/test8c.cpp:3:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_map.h:1079:7: note: candidate: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::find(const key_type&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::shared_ptr<gdwg::Graph<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>::Node>; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::shared_ptr<gdwg::Graph<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>::Node> > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::shared_ptr<gdwg::Graph<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>::Node> > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
       find(const key_type& __x)
       ^~~~
```

This is the code for deleteNode.

```
template <typename N, typename E>
void Graph<N, E>::deleteNode(const N& node) noexcept {
    auto findNode = nodes_.find(node);
    if (findNode != nodes_.end()) {

        for (auto edge: findNode->second->incomingEdges_) {

            // find the node which has incoming edges into the deleted node
            auto originNodeOfIncomingEdge = edge->dest.lock(); // origin node of incoming edge to deleted node

            auto nodeVal = originNodeOfIncomingEdge->val_;
            std::cout << "Print out value of origin node of incoming edge to deleted node: " << nodeVal << std::endl;


            // delete the edge from the node
            //originNodeOfIncomingEdge->edges_.erase(edge);


            auto findLinkingNode1 = nodes_.find(originNodeOfIncomingEdge);
            if (findLinkingNode1 == nodes_.end()) throw std::runtime_error("deleteNode: findLinkingNode1 DNE");

        }

        findNode->second.reset(); // deletes managed object of the shared_ptr
        nodes_.erase(findNode); // removes the node from the map container


    }
}
```

The following is some of the declarations of my Graph class:

```
template <typename N, typename E> class Graph {

    private:
        struct Node;
        struct Edge;

        struct Node {
            N val_;
            int numEdges_;
            int numIncomingEdges_;
            std::set<std::shared_ptr<Edge>> edges_;
            std::set<std::shared_ptr<Edge>> incomingEdges_;
            Node() {}
            Node(const N x) : val_{x} { numEdges_=0; }
            void printNode(N n);
            ~Node();
            void update();
        };

        struct Edge {
            std::weak_ptr<Node> orig;
            std::weak_ptr<Node> dest;
            E val_;
            Edge(std::shared_ptr<Node> o, std::shared_ptr<Node> d, E x);
            Edge() {};
            void printEdge();
            ~Edge();
        };
```

Comment: the error said that `originNodeOfIncomingEdge` has type `std::shared_ptr<gdwg::Graph<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>::Node>` instead of `std::string`

Comment: Oh is it? The error code I don't quite understand it. So what do I do?

Comment: Post your Graph class https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Just posted the class through edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error said that `originNodeOfIncomingEdge` has type `std::shared_ptr<gdwg::Graph<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>‌​, int>::Node>` instead of `std::string`

I believe this is what you want:

```
auto findLinkingNode1 = nodes_.find(nodeVal);
if (findLinkingNode1 == nodes_.end())
   // logic to handle
```

Comment: tests/Graph.tem: In instantiation of ‘void gdwg::Graph<N, E>::deleteNode(const N&) [with N = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; E = int]’:
tests/test8c.cpp:24:23:   required from here
tests/Graph.tem:559:101: error: throw will always call terminate() [-Werror=terminate]
    if (findLinkingNode1 == nodes_.end()) throw std::runtime_error("deleteNode: findLinkingNode1 DNE");
                                                                                                     ^

Comment: I don't understand, how come we need to get the ->val_ (nodeVal) for this find, as compared to the previous auto findNode = nodes_.find(node); in the outside of the for-loop?

Comment: your function: `void Graph<N, E>::deleteNode(const N& node)` is declared `noexcept`, you can't throw inside it

Comment: @iteong in line 3: `auto findNode = nodes_.find(node);` node has type `const N&` aka `const std::string&`

Comment: So how do I delete the node? Is it the following? auto findLinkingNode1 = nodes_.find(nodeVal);
   findLinkingNode1->second->edges_.erase(edge);

Comment: You haven't post full declaration of your class, hence I need to guess, but, I believe your map is `std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<gdwg::Graph<std::string, int>::Node>>`, then `edge->dest.lock()` is a `std::shared_ptr<gdwg::Graph<std::string, int>::Node>`

Comment: I tried to delete the node with the following but doesn't seem to work: findLinkingNode1->second->edges_.erase(edge);

Comment: delete the node from what? from that map or that set inside a node, it's another question though

Comment: Sorry typo...too late at night lol. Delete the edges for the linking node I meant. Coz the original question asked about trying to delete the node, but also needing to delete the incoming and outgoing edges that were connecting that node to other nodes. The edges stored in the deleted node will be automatically deleted when the node is deleted, but I also need to delete the edges that used to be connected to the deleted node, that are also attached to other nodes (hence the linkingNode that I need to find so i can delete the stored edges from there too).

Comment: anyway, please take some C++ book and learn, ask question like this won't help you with further task

Answer (score 1):

Here the compiler is saying that the map is constructed with a key of type std::string and you are calling find with a key of type Node. 
Can you try `auto findLinkingNode1 = nodes_.find(originNodeOfIncomingEdge->val_);` ? 
The better if you share the call of your `void Graph<N, E>::deleteNode(const N& node) noexcept` and or instanciation of Graph object.

Comment: tests/Graph.tem: In instantiation of ‘void gdwg::Graph<N, E>::deleteNode(const N&) [with N = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; E = int]’:
tests/test8c.cpp:24:23:   required from here
tests/Graph.tem:559:101: error: throw will always call terminate() [-Werror=terminate]
    if (findLinkingNode1 == nodes_.end()) throw std::runtime_error("deleteNode: findLinkingNode1 DNE");
                                                                                                     ^